# If images are set to display: none do they still load?

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you hide an image by setting the display property to `none`, does the browser still load that image file via HTTP Request? Because I have a list of images, their display property is set to `none`, except the first image which is the default picture. Once the users click the next button, I want to show the image 2 and set the display property for the other images to `none`. I am asking this to make my website faster.

Comment: Have you tried it? The browser's dev tools have a network tab that shows what's being loaded.

Comment: Images are loaded as soon as a src attribute is specified, even image is not added in the DOM

Answer (score 14):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qYEd4/)**

Yes, the image is loaded. One of the solutions is using another attribute of `src`:

```
<img data-src="http://placekitten.com/300/300?" />
<img data-src="http://placekitten.com/400/400?" />
<img data-src="http://placekitten.com/500/500?" />
```

Then when you want to show one of them, just setting the `src`
attribute of it to its `data-src`:

```
// showing the second one
var $img = $('img').eq(1);
$img.attr('src', $img.attr('data-src'));
```

Then its being loaded.

---

### background-image

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FSKCf/)**

The other solution is using `background-image` instead of `img` tag, in this case, it will not loaded, until its getting visible:

```
<div class="div-as-image" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300?);"></div>
<div class="div-as-image" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/400/400?);"></div>
<div class="div-as-image" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500?);"></div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.div-as-image {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

Now, if you make one of them visible, its image getting loaded:

```
// showing the second one
var $div = $('.div-as-image').eq(1);
$div.css('display', 'block');
```

- This method won't work in Chrome, as it loaded the `background-image` on `none` elements too.

Comment: Note that this approach does not degrade gracefully. When JavaScript is disabled or unavailable, no images are displayed since they don't have a `src` attribute. Of course, if your image slideshow does not degrade either (e.g. fall back to a list of images), there's no use in trying to get your images to degrade: non-JavaScript users will still be left out. That's more of a design choice, though.

Comment: I like this solution, very neat

Comment: background-image doesn't work at all. Even the jsFiddle Demo loads all pictures on refresh without clicking any button. (Chrome PC)

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The image is loaded, it is just not visible due to the CSS rule.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late, but I would recommend using the [Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) by [Mika Tuupola](http://www.appelsiini.net/) (at least that's what I'm going to do).

It does a good job of not loading images until they are going to be displayed in the window and also waits for them to have a display value that renders the image visible.  Not to mention, it's pretty easy to use.

Godspeed.

Answer (score -2):

You could load images from the folder using ajax, and then jQuery.load() function for the img element.

Comment: Not only does this not answer the question, but there's no reason to use Ajax for loading images. `var img = new Image(); img.src = 'whatever.jpg';` preloads the image if necessary, or you can just hide the image tag and let it load in the background.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you can set `background: none;` to prevent a `background-image` of loading. See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grsmto/7d15fuhm/4/

Tested on Chrome 39. For Firefox 34, `display: none;` is sufficient.

Edit: example updated

Comment: Chrome downloads everything for me now.